# MySQL: Is there a straight-forwards way of ensuring that every instance of a given character is actually the same character?

Tags: mysql

[image: Characters that look the same aren't really the same]

I have a few different data sources that I combined to populate a column of a table
(with the IPA of words as it happens, although that is probably not important).

Now I'm having trouble getting other data to link to or match with it
and I think I've figured out why, almost.
It's because characters that look the same aren't really the same.

Is there a straight-forwards way of ensuring that every instance of a given character
is always really the same character?

Comment: When you say that you want to match on the same character, what exactly do you mean?  Clearly the two characters in your image are _not the same_.  Do you want them to match as if they were?

Comment: Yes, I imported two separate sources of string data (as it happens the phonetic IPA which corresponds to a series of words). In order to identify the sound that goes with each phoneme, I need the IPA data to be consistent - so I can match it with a lookup table. Currently some words have IPA where characters are actually different characters (ie. different byte values) ... so they don't actually match the lookup table. 

It doesn't really matter to me which value gets used for a given IPA character as long as it is the same (which currently it isn't).

Answer (score 0):

Running SQL queries like this one below against the data in the MySQL Workbench app seems like it may be working to fix the problem.
Although at first sight it looks like you are just replacing the character with the same character - it may be that you aren't.

```
UPDATE words 
SET ipa=Replace(ipa, "‍ɪ", "ɪ")
```

This might seem trivially obvious, but partly I originally asked the question because when I initially tried to do this, it didn't seem to be working - and that made me think I was missing something e.g. that I was not sufficiently understanding the role of Collation and Charset in this. In fact I have played around with Collation parameters and Charset values in the table definition as well, so that may have been part of why it didn't initially appear to fix the problem, but now possibly it is fixing it.

Sorry to be vague about this, but that's the best I've got so far.

As a side comment, it's pretty silly to have multiple different characters have the same visual appearance in the first place ... it is bound to lead to trouble of the kind I have had here.